# Sistema de vestibular usando JAVA

Tags: java

Tenho um trabalho da faculdade para fazer, que é criar um sistema de vestibular.
O trabalho está no link, [clique aqui](http://goo.gl/goCCYh), e estou em dúvida no seguinte tópico:

> O programa deverá ler do arquivo "vestibular.txt" os dados dos alunos,
>   verificar quais são os alunos aprovados para cada curso e,
>   posteriormente, gravar em um arquivo denominado
>   "aprovados_cursotal.txt" (um para cada curso), ordenados pela nota do
>   aluno. Se dois ou mais alunos tiverem a mesma nota, os mesmos devem
>   ser ordenados pelo seu nome e, em caso de nomes iguais, ordenar pela
>   matrícula.

Já criei todas as classes citadas no link. A classe arquivo, já esta salvando todos os dados necessário no arquivo vestibular.txt. Só que não sei como fazer os outros dois arquivos filtrando os aprovados de cada curso de acordo com as notas.

-- 
Classe's que já fiz. Google Drive https://drive.google.com/a/sga.pucminas.br/folderview?id=0ByaGP-vb3NW7cVBYUzN0VjFEWGM&usp=sharing

Comment: Então coloca o que você fez.

Comment: @RaulGoulart O problema que você citou na verdade é um tanto amplo e pode ser dividido em problemas menores. Acho melhor você começar com um deles, com o qual esteja tendo dificuldade, e explique como você tentou atacá-lo e quais dificuldades encontrou. Além de colocar o que fez, como o bigown falou.

Comment: Dividir para conquistar! Faça uma pergunta rápida e objetiva que conseguiremos te responder. Veja o guia [ask]

Comment: Raul, vendo sua pergunta anteriormente fiz duas classes que resolvem o problema, vou postar e você verifica, não está tão de acordo com o que o link pede. Mas você pode observar o meu código e depois dizer o que não ta conseguindo, ou especificar o que não tá conseguindo.

Comment: @bigown, postei o conteudo que ja fiz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem, desenvolvi uma solução que atende mais ou menos o que você quer. A solução ler um arquivo vestibular.txt com os atributos separados por vírgula, então é criado um objeto Aluno para cada linha (cada aluno no caso) e então é salvo em uma ArrayList para ser processado e então gerado o novo documento, segue o código.

Primeiro temos a classe Aluno.java, essa classe vamos usar para poder manipular o nosso aluno, no caso ordenar a lista pela nota.

**Aluno.java**

```
public class Aluno implements Comparable<Aluno> {

    private String nome;
    private String curso;
    private int inscricao;
    private double nota;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }


    //Outros getters e setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Aluno a) {
        if(this.nota > a.nota) return 1;
        if(this.nota > a.nota) return -1;
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

Na classe aluno implementei a interface Comparable, sobrescrevi o método compareTo, para quando usar o Collections.sort() poder ordenar pela nota.

A classe aluno estando pronta, agora segue a classe ProcessadorNotas. A classe está bem comentada. Mas o que basicamente ela faz: Ler o arquivo vestibular.txt e separa os atributos que estão entre as virgulas. Após isso é criado um aluno para salvar os atributos nele e então adiciona-lo na lista. Após todos os alunos adicionados na lista é possível fazer o Collections.sort, que irá ordernar os alunos por nota.

Então depois da lista ordenada eu fiz apenas um Foreach salvando apenas os alunos que tem nota acima de 8.

**ProcessadorNotas.java**

```
public class ProcessadorNotas {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Aluno aluno = null;
        ArrayList<Aluno> listaDeAlunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("vestibular.txt"));

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String linha = sc.nextLine();
            //Separamos os dados por virgula, e cada campo será armazenado em uma posição da array.
            String dados[] = linha.split(",");
            //Criamos um objeto aluno e setamos os seus atributos para depois colarmos na lista.
            aluno = new Aluno();
            aluno.setNome(dados[0]);
            aluno.setInscricao(Integer.parseInt(dados[1]));
            aluno.setNota(Double.parseDouble(dados[2]));
            aluno.setCurso(dados[3]);
            //Adicionamos o aluno a lista.
            listaDeAlunos.add(aluno);
        }       

        //Vamos ordernar os alunos por notas, então iremos apenas ver quais estão acima da média na hora de escrever.

        Collections.sort(listaDeAlunos);

        //Agora já temos a lista de alunos, agora vamos escrever um outro arquivo com o resultado_vestibular
        //Vamos supor que para ser aprovado, o aluno tem que ter nota 8. 

        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("aprovados_vestibular.txt");

        for(Aluno a : listaDeAlunos) {
            if(a.getNota() > 8) {
                ps.print(a.getNome()+",");
                ps.print(String.valueOf(a.getInscricao())+",");
                ps.print(String.valueOf(a.getNota())+",");
                ps.print(a.getCurso());
                ps.println();
            }
        }       
        ps.close();
    }   
}
```

Caso tenha alguma dúvida posta ai nos comentários, valeu.

Comment: nao consegui ordena a lista nao.

Comment: Na classe aluno tu inplementou o comparable?

Comment: nao aprendi isso ainda u.u

Comment: Ih cara, então se tu não aprendeu ainda, provavelmente o professor não vai aceitar desse jeito =/

Comment: @RaulGoulart tenta fazer sozinho, senão nunca mais aprendes a programar...